# Pose vs Rest position are different

Tags: rigging

I'm using a manuel Bastioni model and trying to add a facial rig. When I weight paint the eye lids even though they are at 100% they don't follow the bone all the way. Only when I remove them from the head deform bone will they follow the eyelid bone. 
The other problem which might be related is that pose and rest mode are different. I tried to find the IK constraint that might be causing this, but I can't... Any help would be appreciated. link to the blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13uL7Bso-9EbK9btwYCpp1Tp_xsf815J1/view?usp=sharing
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Skeleton*, display all the layers so that you can see all the bones, now you can check the influence of the different bones, for example the head bone has an influence on the lids so of course the lid bones won't influence them 100%.

Also, if the bones in *Pose* mode have a different position, it's because they are influenced by some constraints like *Copy Rotation* or *IK*. To get exactly the same position as in *Edit* mode it may need some small bone readjustments.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm a bit confused with the workflow then. When weight painting and you have multiple bones. Is it that vertices can belong to only one vertex group to be 100% influenced by a bone? For example in my case the head bone controls all the vertices in the head. What's the proper way to add eyelid control? Should I be removing these vertices from the head bone? 

thanks

Comment: exactly, remove the lids from the head bone influence. You can use the Vertex Groups list: Select the lid vertex groups in your 3D scene, then in the Vertex Groups list select the vertex groups that has the name of the head bone, then click the Remove button... now the head bone has no more influence on this part of the mesh

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I also found that if I have "Auto Normalize" on when painting that it seems to automatically reduce the influence of the head bone on the painted vertices. What do you think of that approach?

Comment: I don't use this option so sorry, I can not help you on this matter  :/